# check if username exists in real-time through AJAX in php with mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a project in php/MySQL that requires me to check the username in real-time means as the user inputs the username.
This is my **username.php** where the user actually enters the username & password and from where the **check.php** is triggered...

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#username").change(function(){
             $("#message").html("<img src='images/loader.gif' /> checking...");


        var username = $("#username").val();

          $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"check.php",
                data:"username =" + username,
                    success:function(data){
                    if(data==0){
                        $("#message").html("<img src='images/tick.png' /><span style='font-size:13px; color: black'> Username available</span>");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#message").html("<img src='images/err.png' /><span style=font-size:13px; color: red'> Username already taken</span>");
                    }
                }
             });

        });

     });

   </script>
   </head>

   <body>

   <table>
    <tr>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><td>
            <td id="message"><td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /><td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```

This is the **check.php** where the username is checked in the database.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "hilbi", "userdb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{

  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

  // $username = $_POST["username"];

  $username = 'hilbi';

  $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =   '$username' ");

  $find = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  echo $find;

  mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

Now the **check.php** is working fine (which I checked through executing it alone and it returns **1** on finding the username and **vice versa**)
However when I execute the **username.php** *it always returns **Username already taken***. It seems it actually does not look in the database at all where actually there is no such username. 

Any kind of help will be much appreciated...

Comment: You are sending username wrong

Comment: try adding alert(data); inside ur success callback function, so you can see what is getting returned from php

Comment: @Muhammad M Yeah I had to change it to a static username after the dynamic was not working just to make sure the query is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send your data in javascript using jQuery like this:

```
$.post( "check.php", { user: $("#username").val() }, function (data){
  if(data=='1'){
   //do 1
  }
  elseif(data=='0'){
    //do 0
  }
});
```

In your check.php get username like this

```
//some basic validation
if(!isset($_POST['user'] || empty($_POST['user']))
{
   echo '0'; exit();
}

$username = trim($_POST['user']);
```

For this to work properly you check.php must return either 1 or 0, do not echo mysql errors there or whatsoever. if any error occur, just echo 0.

Comment: You pointed out the correct problem and gave the correct solution. thankyou.

Comment: glad I could be of help, jquery is the beast when you know how to handle it.

Comment: Exactly. A beast when you cannot find a solution to a problem. Best when you actually find. :-)

Comment: I know this is sorted but one small tip, with your select query to check if the user exists, don't use "SELECT *" but instead just "SELECT id", it's faster and less stress on the database. You could also add "LIMIT 1" to the end because once you've found one you then know that username exists and there's no need to find more.

Answer (score 2):

soo I spent some time looking for, and testing answer, so I should, posted my results and what working for me..

```
html, or php form:

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<form class="a16" action="register.php" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
                                    <label for="userName" class=" ">Użytkownik:</label>

<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" id="userName1" onBlur="checkAvailability()">

      <span id="user-availability-status"></span> 
<p><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" /></p>

 <script type="text/javascript">     

function checkAvailability() {
$("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "proceser.php",
data:'userName='+$("#userName1").val(),
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
$("#user-availability-status").html(data);
$("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){}
});
}
</script>

and proceser.php :

<?php
 include 'dbconnect.php';   //standard datebase local connection..

 if(isset($_POST['userName']) && $_POST['userName']!="") {
     if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userName = ?')) {
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['userName']);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->store_result();
         $numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
         if ($numRows > 0) {
             echo "<span class=''> Username Not Available.</span>";
         } else {
             echo "<span class=''> Username Available.</span>";
         }
     }
 }
$con->close();
ob_end_flush();

?>


Thank you!:)
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining what is going on in the code as opposed pasting a large code block which is difficult to read and relate back to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
data:"username =" + username

data:"username=" + username
```

you must delete space after username and all work

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass $username variable correctly.

Single quotes php vars are treated as plain strings and variables aren't evaluated.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = " .  $username . ";");
```

OR

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = {$username}");
```

Comment: thanks for your response however this seems to be not the problem as the query is returning a boolean.

Comment: He is using double quotes and his PHP code works all right. While your code makes this query fail.